# OTB Orfeo Toolbox QGIS on Mac M1 ARM machine

Tags: qgis

I am having a difficult time getting the OTB plugin to work on QGIS 3.22 on my MacBook running M1 ARM. I followed the directions listed on this page to use a Docker Image for install

[Orfeo ToolBox Docker Image Install](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Installation.html#docker-image)

and I was able to successfully create a container for orfeotoolbox/otb:8.0.1 as shown in the image below.

[image: Orfeo ToolBox Docker Container]

However, when I go to QGIS under Settings > Options > Processing > Providers > OTB there is no *activate* option. I attempted to add the OTB application folder and OTB folder directories but I was not able to physically locate the image on the disk. Docker says it is located at ENV OTB_APPLICATION_PATH=/opt/otb/lib/otb/applications but I cannot find that path on my Mac and QGIS does not recognize the path either.

I feel like I'm overlooking something simple here but I can't crack this nut for some reason.

Has anyone had success in connecting the QGIS OTB plugin on a MacBook M1 ARM machine?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to say I have the same problem as the thread. I followed the instruction here, https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Installation.html, but still got confused. It's great to know if anyone have the experience to install it. My laptop is based on Apple M1 chip.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).