ORFEO OTB use on QGIS installed through Docker on Mac M1
I am having a really hard time using the docker container and linking it to QGIS. I could download the files and save them on DISK. QGIS OTB reads the functions but does not execute them.
I have an active container with the correct amd64 binaries but really can't seem to make the connection between docker and QGIS.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/437323/115
